# Parse list of lists containing xml in r to data frame

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to parse a list returned from the ZillowR API.  It sure looks like XML, but I get only errors trying to parse it.  I'd like to put it in a single row data frame with certain nodes being column names and their values being the value.  The data frame would contain a column for zipId, address, zipcode, last sold price, etc...

```
> class(listings)
[1] "list"
> class(listings$response)
[1] "XMLNode"          "RXMLAbstractNode" "XMLAbstractNode"  "oldClass"        
> listings$response
<response>
 <results>
  <result>
   <zpid>106502569</zpid>
   <address>
    <street>2914 N Lincoln Rd</street>
    <zipcode>49431</zipcode>
    <city>Ludington</city>
    <state>MI</state>
    <latitude>44.009122</latitude>
    <longitude>-86.439803</longitude>
   </address>
   <FIPScounty>26105</FIPScounty>
   <useCode>SingleFamily</useCode>
   <taxAssessmentYear>2015</taxAssessmentYear>
   <taxAssessment>64400.0</taxAssessment>
   <yearBuilt>1992</yearBuilt>
   <lotSizeSqFt>217800</lotSizeSqFt>
   <finishedSqFt>1500</finishedSqFt>
   <bathrooms>2.0</bathrooms>
   <bedrooms>2</bedrooms>
   <lastSoldDate>12/05/2016</lastSoldDate>
   <lastSoldPrice currency="USD">1</lastSoldPrice>
   <zestimate>
    <amount currency="USD">153718</amount>
    <last-updated>12/05/2016</last-updated>
    <oneWeekChange deprecated="true"/>
    <valueChange duration="30" currency="USD">-1443</valueChange>
    <valuationRange>
     <low currency="USD">141421</low>
     <high currency="USD">170627</high>
    </valuationRange>
    <percentile>0</percentile>
   </zestimate>
   <localRealEstate/>
  </result>
 </results>
</response>
```

And when I try to parse it...

```
> library(xml2)
> xml_find_all(listings$response, "zpid")
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "XMLNode"
> xml_name(listings$response)
Error in UseMethod("xml_name") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_name' applied to an object of class "XMLNode"
> xmlParse(listings$response)
Error in file.exists(file) : invalid 'file' argument
```

[listings variable structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBrc4.png)

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Comment: Have you tried the `XML` package? Functions like `xmlToDataFrame` , `xmlParse` might help out here.

Comment: Yes, but it returns errors - xmlParse(listings$response) returns "Error in file.exists(file) : invalid 'file' argument" - xml_find_all(listings$response, "zpid") returns "no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "c('XMLNode', 'RXMLAbstractNode', 'XMLAbstractNode', 'oldClass')""

Comment: You've already got parsed XML (that was parsed with the `XML` pacakge, hence the output from `class(listings$response)` and the error `no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "XMLNode"`).

Comment: hrbrmstr - then how do I pull values out of it?  If I build a sample XML string I can use xml_find_all to pull out values.  I've updated the original post to include an image of the listings variable from the RStudio values screen.